# Swapping alternate digits of a given number without using arrays

Tags: c, algorithm

Swapping alternate digits of a given number without using arrays, e.g.:

```
 Input: 54687
Output: 45867
```

What is the proper algorithm to solve this without using an array? I was asked this question at an interview and still can't figure out the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try converting to a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat each pair of decimal digits as a base-100 digit, and transform it a base-100 digit at a time.  The only "trick" is that if the input has an odd number of decimal digits, you keep the least significant decimal digit as is.

For example:

```
 Input │ Output │ Operation
═══════╪════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════
 54687 │        │ Initial state
 5468  │      7 │ Keep least significant decimal digit,
       │        │ because odd number of decimal digits.
 54    │    867 │ Swap next two digits (68), and add to output.
       │  45867 │ Swap next two digits (45), and add to output.
```

In pseudocode, you could implement it as two functions. The first one calculates the number of decimal digits in `value`, i.e. `ceil(log10(value))`. You can also do it "brute-force" way using integer data types:

```
Function DecimalDigits(value):
    Let  digits = 1

    While (value >= 10):
        Let  digits = digits + 1
        Let  value = value / 10    # Truncate, or round down
    End While

    Return digits
End Function
```

or a slightly "optimized" version, which uses a smaller number of divisions and modulos by counting groups of decimal digits:

```
Function DecimalDigits(value):
    Let  digits = 1
    Let  value = value / 10
    While (value > 9999999):
        Let  digits = digits + 8
        Let  value = value / 100000000
    End While
    If (value > 999):
        Let  digits = digits + 4
        Let  value = value / 10000
    End If
    If (value > 9):
        Let  digits = digits + 2
        Let  value = value / 100
    End If
    If (value > 0):
        Let  digits = digits + 1
    End If

    Return digits
End Function
```

But for true pseudocode, expressing the intent should be enough:

```
Function DecimalDigits(value):
    # Number of decimal digits in value
    Return ceil(log10(value))
End Function
```

The actual second function does the pairwise transforms:

```
Function SwapAlternateDigits(value):

    # Remember if negative. We operate on nonnegative 'value'.
    If (value < 0) Then:
        Let  value = -value
        Let  sign = -1
    Else:
        Let  sign = +1
    End If

    # If there is an odd number of digits,
    # keep the rightmost (least significant)
    # digit as-is.
    If (IsOdd(DecimalDigits(value))) Then:
        Let  result = value % 10
        Let  value = value / 10
        Let  base = 10
    Else:
        Let  result = 0
        Let  base = 1
    End If

    # Loop over the remaining pairs of decimal digits.
    While (value > 0):
        Let  lower = value % 10
        Let  value = value / 10
        Let  upper = value % 10
        Let  value = value / 10

        Let  result = result + base * (upper + 10 * lower)

        Let  base = base * 100
    End While

    Return sign * result
End Function
```

Note that in both pseudocode functions above, `/` denotes integer division with truncation, and `%` the modulo operator, the same way they are used in e.g. [c](/questions/tagged/c).

The `base` variable is the power of ten that keeps track of the position of the next digit pair to be added to `result`. `lower` is the lower decimal digit, and `upper` the upper decimal digit extracted from `value`. Obviously, `upper + 10*lower` is the value of the decimal digit pair when swapped.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not a number theorist you could have made some progress by examining the difference between the two numbers (and if my human resources department insisted on my asking a candidate this question, I think that's what I'd expect them to do). If you are a number theorist then the answer will pop out of your head quite quickly. It is, for a positive number;

1. The first two digits are in the 1000s position (`a = 1000`, say).
2. The first two digits differ by `-1` (`b = -1` say; note the sign convention).
3. You need to add `9 * a * b` to `Input`. i.e. `-9000`. That swaps the first two digits. Then we continue:
4. The next two digits are in the 10s position (`a = 10`).
5. The digits differ by `+2` (`b = 2`)
6. Again, you add `9 * a * b`, i.e. `+180`.

A strong candidate will point out that `Input` might be too big to fit into an `int`, depending on your platform.

Note that you get the position of the most significant digits by repeated integer division by 10 until 0 is reached.

Comment: There are some subtle points to worry about in coding that up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, indeed it's not easy: I'm not sure I would solve it under interview conditions and without a couple of debugs.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It is much, much easier to treat the digits as symbols (i.e. characters). With this solution you cannot handle unbounded natural numbers.

Comment: @Acorn; But that necessitates the most unsatisfactory conversion from a numerical to a string-based solution.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Indeed, I am assuming by "input"/"output" OP meant `stdin`/`stdout` (i.e. like in programming competitions).

Comment: The title says "without the use of arrays" — that precludes conversion to a string (because of course it is trivial if you've got a string).  It isn't 100% clear whether the input is a number passed to a function which returns another number: `int mangler(int); int result = mangler(value);` or whether the input is to be read from a file stream, or what.  Interview questions are often vague on such issues, to see whether you're willing to ask for clarifications.  Asking for the clarifications is a sign of strength in a candidate, at least in my view.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're hired!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not at all. First, "without the use of arrays" can be understood as "without storing the input into an string/array". In other words, a solution which requires unbounded memory -- i.e. not a FSM. Second, even understanding it as a `int -> int` function; you can always iterate through the digits and apply the other solution without the need of an array.

Answer (score 1):

This problem only requires to remember one character at most. In pseudocode:

```
forever {
    c = read()
    print(read())
    print(c)
}
```

Note that you have to handle `EOF` appropriately: output the last character if the number of digits is odd (i.e. if you get the `EOF` in the first `read()`).

---

Note that this problem can even be solved without declaring any variable (in the C sense). For that, think about the problem as a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that encodes the information about each combination of characters (i.e. transitions to a different set of states for the first character).

Just to prove the point (of course, do not write code this way), such DFA "tree" in C using a `switch` inside a `switch` ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b470f2bab3429560), [Dissassembly at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/1yiWHn)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        switch (getchar()) {
        case '0':
            switch (getchar()) {
                case '0': putchar('0'); break;
                ...
                case '9': putchar('9'); break;
                default:  putchar('0'); return 0;
            }
            putchar('0');
            break;

        ...

        case '9':
            switch (getchar()) {
                case '0': putchar('0'); break;
                ...
                case '9': putchar('9'); break;
                default:  putchar('9'); return 0;
            }
            putchar('9');
            break;

        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int in = 354687;                // Input number   
int out = 0;                    // Output number
int decimal = 10;               // The current decimal we are working with
int subtractor = 0;             // Subtractor to make sure we ingore previous variables
int residue = 0;                // The current decimal's value

for (int i=1; i<8; i++){        // Limit to 8 chars

    // Move the current char
    residue = (in-subtractor)%decimal;
    if (i%2)                    // If even, need to move digit left
        out += residue * 10; 
    else                        // Else move digit right
        out += residue / 10;

    // Get ready for next time around
    subtractor += residue;
    decimal *= 10;
}

printf("\n\nOut: %d\n", in);
printf("Out: %d\n", out);
```

Comment: `int in = 354687` is not portable, also you need to guard against negative inputs.

Comment: Unless you work in an embedded environment with 16-bit `int` types, the assignment `int in = 354687;` is not going to cause trouble, @Bathsheba.  The vast majority of C programmers do not work in such stringent environments.